# GetProcAddress with all loaded libraries

Tags: c++, c, winapi, dll

With `dlopen` you can provide `NULL` as the library name and get a handle that allows you to find a symbol in *any* of the loaded libraries:

> If filename is a NULL pointer, then the returned handle is for the
>   main program. When given to dlsym(), this handle causes a search for a
>   symbol in the main program, followed by all shared libraries loaded at
>   program startup, and then all shared libraries loaded by dlopen() with
>   the flag RTLD_GLOBAL.

Can you do the same with `GetProcAddress`? I want to search for the presence of a Windows API but different libraries are loaded in Windows 8.

I know what libraries are loaded by looking in the COFF headers, I guess I could loop through the handles there...

This is the code I'm currently using:

`.hpp`

```
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

/**
 * @~english
 * Looks up a Windows API function. Make sure you set @c _WIN32_WINNT so that the definition is available at compile
 * time.
 * @par Example
 * @code
 * # undef _WIN32_WINNT
 * # define _WIN32_WINNT 0x600
 * # include <system/inc/nt/windows.h>
 * static const auto initialize_srw_lock_ptr = FunctionPtrLookup(InitializeSRWLock, "kernel32");
 * @endcode
 * @param function the function definition to lookup
 * @retval nullptr the function did not exist on this version of Windows
 * @returns a function pointer to invoke
 */
#define FunctionPtrLookup(function, library) \
  FunctionLookup<decltype(function)>(#function, library)

/**
 * @~english
 * The return type of FunctionLookup
 */
typedef void(*FunctionLookupPtr)();

/**
 * @~english
 * Looks up a Windows API function. 
 * @param name the name of the function to find in the library
 * @retval nullptr the function did not exist on this version of Windows
 * @returns a function pointer to invoke
 * @see FunctionPtrLookup
 */
FunctionLookupPtr FunctionLookup(const std::string& name, const std::string& library);

/// @copydoc FunctionLookup
template<typename Signature>
const Signature * FunctionLookup(const std::string& name, const std::string& library) {
  return reinterpret_cast<const Signature*>(FunctionLookup(name, library));
}
```

`.cpp`

```
FunctionLookupPtr FunctionLookup(const std::string& name, const std::string& library) {
  const auto wide_library = Utf8ToWide(library);
  const auto lib = LoadLibraryW(wide_library.c_str());
  if (!lib) {
    return nullptr;
  }
  return reinterpret_cast<FunctionLookupPtr>(GetProcAddress(lib, name.c_str()));
}
```

Ideally, I'd want to remove the `library` variable.

Comment: I'm somewhat curious as to why you're not just `LoadLibrary`'ing the DLL you want, and *then* calling `GetProcAddress`? If the API you want isn't present, presumably your `LoadLibrary` or `GetProcAddress` will fail, giving you an answer without requiring this sort of library search.

Comment: This is _just_ for finding WINAPI functions that are not supported in certain versions of Windows. The problem is that for Windows 8 the function are no longer in `kernel32`. Also the function could be in `user32` or `kernel32` and it will be an easier API to just find the function. I might just be doing something more complicated than its worth so welcome to suggestions!

Comment: If you know where the APIs are supposed to be located in different versions of Windows, you could use the [`IsVersion*OrGreater` functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn424972(v=vs.85).aspx) to determine where your APIs are supposed to be located, then `LoadLibrary`/`GetProcAddress` the necessary library/function combo. If you want to give me an example of one or two of the APIs in question, I could try to whip up a quick example for you.

Comment: Well slim read write locks are the first one I've implemented. So `InitializeSRWLock` would be the first one. But I'm hitting others.

Comment: Hmm, got that wrong SRW locks are always in `kernel32`, on my phone right now, can't remember which API was split.

Comment: Yeah, I was just looking up `InitializeSRWLock` and MSDN didn't note any non-kernel32 locations for it. Feel free to ping me if you can recall which API(s) you're having issues with, though. I'd love to take a shot at this.

Comment: So you want you library to be usable for both windows store and desktop apps? If you target only windows store app then it should suffice to check on MSDN if function is available, if not then just dont use it.

Comment: The library needs to target cross platform. So needs to support both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [EnumProcessModules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682631%28VS.85%29.aspx) to enumerate all loaded modules for current process, use example from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, if you call `PrintModules` with `GetCurrentProcessId()`, it will enumerate all HMODULE handles (value is in `hMods[i]`) for current process. You can use them with GetProcAddress to find your function.

You must be aware that its possible to find the same named functions in different dll-s, mostly you know dll name for WinAPI function.

Comment: If you know the exact DLL that exports the desired symbol, you can use `GetModuleHandle()` to check if that DLL is currently loaded in the calling process.

Comment: Note that if you didn't load the library then the code that loaded it might unload the library while you are still using it. Also, in Windows it is considered poor form to hunt for a function in this way. How do you know that the function X in a random DLL does what you think?

Comment: The library will be loaded as its part of the Windows API. Well I would assume that people wouldn't implement functions that are named the same as a WINAPI function. This won't be a public function, just needed internally in my system abstraction layer. To be 100% honest i haven't actually tested the code on Windows 8 or 8.1 yet, so not even sure how the split up WINAPI libraries are loaded. Maybe you do have to manually load them.