# Win32 equivalent of dlopen(NULL, ...)

Tags: c, windows, dll, dlopen, getprocaddress

Is there a simple equivalent to `dlopen(NULL, ...)` on Windows?

The behavior on POSIX (or at least Linux) is: the returned handle can be used to find exported symbols on the executable *as well as on dependent shared objects*. To put simply, following

```
void *lib = dlopen(NULL, RTLD_NOW);
```

doing `dlsym(lib, "memcpy")` will return the symbol for `memcpy`.

On win32, `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` is almost an equivalent, except that the set of dependent DLLs is not searched for symbols; `GetProcAddress(lib, "memcpy")` returns `NULL`.

Any idea? Note: of course, in my application, I don't want to merely access `memcpy`, but some more complicated symbol, and from a FFI.

Comment: This looks like it should answer your question: [**Get address for symbol in current process in Windows**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45114078/get-address-for-symbol-in-current-process-in-windows)

Comment: I've found a likely duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23437007/getprocaddress-with-all-loaded-libraries

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check out https://github.com/dlfcn-win32/dlfcn-win32 which is a `dlopen()` implementation for Windows (using mentioned functions `GetModuleHandle` / `GetProcAddress`).